# Calling python Script using ProcessBuilder to create a graph in XLSX sworkbook

Tags: python, java, pandas, xlsxwriter, processbuilder

Below  is my java code, I am trying to call a python script from java. The python script job is to create a graph in an xlsx sheet. It works well when I run the python script by itself , but when i call it from java nothing happens - and there is no error either.

public class CallPython {

```
    private String pythonScriptPath;
    
    CallPython(){
        
    }
    
    public void executePythonScript() throws Throwable {
        
        try {
            String pathScript = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\pythonScripts\\script.py";
            //String venvPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\pythonScripts\\venv\\Scripts\\activate";
            ArrayList<String> listCommand = new ArrayList<>();
            listCommand.add("python");
            listCommand.add(pathScript);
            System.out.println("the path : " +pathScript);
            //System.out.println("the venv path : " +venvPath);
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(listCommand);
            builder.redirectErrorStream();
            Process process = builder.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader readerError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            String lines = null;
            
            while((lines=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println("lines "+lines);
            }
           while ((lines= readerError.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(lines);
        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
    }
```

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

```
CallPython newcall = new CallPython();
newcall.executePythonScript();
```

}

}

import pandas as pd

def create_pivot():
# Create a chart object.

```
# Some sample data to plot.
list_data = [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame(list_data)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
excel_file = 'book.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

# Access the XlsxWriter workbook and worksheet objects from the dataframe.
# This is equivalent to the following using XlsxWriter on its own:
#
#    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')
#    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

# Create a chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

# Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data.
chart.add_series({
    'values': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$8',
    'gap': 2,
})

# You can also use array notation to define the chart values.
#    chart.add_series({
#        'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, 1, 7, 1],
#        'gap':        2,
#    })

# Configure the chart axes.
chart.set_y_axis({'major_gridlines': {'visible': False}})

# Turn off chart legend. It is on by default in Excel.
chart.set_legend({'position': 'none'})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart)
print("workbook path: ",workbook)
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
create_pivot()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your process may be freezing because you are not consuming stdout + stderr streams correctly (simultaneously), so if stderr buffer exceeds default size then the application won't be able to continue and will appear to freeze. You can check this by merging stderr to stdout and reading just one stream, not two:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(listCommand);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
process.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);
int rc = process.waitFor();
if (rc != 0)
    throw new RuntimeException("Command: "+pathScript+" failed rc=" + rc);
```

Note that the call `pb.redirectErrorStream()` without argument does nothing in your code example.